# How do I copy repeating sub-structs from one struct to another?

Tags: json, xml, go, struct

I have a struct into which I have unmarshalled a large XML document.
I wish to extract certain elements from the struct and copy them to a new struct. However many of these are repeating structs within another struct

Consider the following example (a small subset of the whole struct):

1) The format of the data coming in

```
type ProductHeader struct {
    Products struct {
        ProductId string `xml:"ProductId"`
        Product   struct {
            PriceBands struct {
                PriceBand []struct {
                    UnitPrice string `xml:"UnitPrice"`
                    LowerQty  string `xml:"LowerQty"`
                    UpperQty  string `xml:"UpperQty"`
                } `xml:"PriceBand"`
            } `xml:"PriceBands"`
        } `xml:"Product"`
    } `xml:"Products"`
}
```

2) The format of the data I wish to output

```
type ProductOut struct {
    ProductId string `json:"productId"`

    PriceBands struct {
        PriceBand []struct {
            UnitPrice    float32 `json:"unitPrice"`
            LowerQty float32 `json:"lowerQty"`
            UpperQty float32 `json:"upperQty"`
        } `json:"priceBand"`
    } `json:"PriceBands"`
}
```

Example XML input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductHeader>
    <Products xmlns="">
        <ProductId>123XYZ</ProductId>
         <Product>
            <PriceBands>
                <PriceBand>
                    <UnitPrice>25.75</UnitPrice>
                    <LowerQty>0.00</LowerQty>
                    <UpperQty>100.00</UpperQty>
                </PriceBand>
                <PriceBand>
                    <UnitPrice>23.99</UnitPrice>
                    <LowerQty>100.01</LowerQty>
                    <UpperQty>1000.00</UpperQty>
                </PriceBand>
                <PriceBand>
                    <UnitPrice>21.00</UnitPrice>
                    <LowerQty>1000.01</LowerQty>
                    <UpperQty>NULL</UpperQty>
                </PriceBand>
            </PriceBands>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</ProductHeader>
```

Example target output

```
{
    "productId" : "123XYZ",
    "priceBands" : [ 
        {
            "unitPrice" : 25.75,
            "lowerQty" : 0.00,
            "upperQty" : 100.00
        },
        {
            "unitPrice" : 23.99,
            "lowerQty" : 100.01,
            "upperQty" : 1000.00
        },
        {
            "unitPrice" : 21.00,
            "lowerQty" : 1000.01,
            "upperQty" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see the products may have multiple price bands. I had initially thought I would simply be able to assign the whole PriceBands element in the form:

```
var p1 ProductHeader
var p2 ProductOut

    p2.PriceBands = p1.Products.Product.PriceBands
```

But this gives a compiler error which makes sense as the number of instances of PriceBand is variable and unknown at compile time.

However this works which also make sense:

```
p2.PriceBands.PriceBand = p1.ProductHeader.PriceBands.PriceBand
```

This leads me to think that I need to iterate through the PriceBands struct somehow.

In Python I could have done something like `For ProductBand in ProductBands` but that syntax does not seem to be available in Go.

What is the correct way in Go to iterate over struct 1) and move the price bands into a concrete instance of struct 2) that I can subsequently unmarshal to JSON as shown in the sample output above.

Comment: The Python's `for Item in Array` loop in go is `for Index, Item := range Array`. To access a Struct fields you can check [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)

Comment: Hi @nigel-ainscoe could you please provide a sample XML? And ideally a go playground link with the working copying that you described? Thanks

Comment: try : p1.ProductHeader.PriceBands

Comment: @ Prakash Kumar - sorry, that was a typo in my question
@Deleplace Example JSON added. No playground at moment - I don't have a working version :-(

Comment: @NigelAinscoe Your `ProductOut` structure does not match that of the desired json. Also you cannot iterate over a struct's fields "natively", you'll need to use reflection for that, although it doesn't seem like that's the correct tool here.

Comment: *"But this gives a compiler error which makes sense ..."* no, it doesn't make sense, the types of those fields are completely identical and there is no compiler error, see here: https://play.golang.com/p/1t4xKWviNNE. If you need help with some code, show us the code you have problems with, something that can reproduce the error.

Comment: @mkopriva - The struct and output are made up so an error is likely. It is the principle of processing an unknown number of repeated structs within an outer struct that I am trying to solve

Comment: @NigelAinscoe https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The `ProductIn` type doesn't match the sample XML (no `Products`) so the data is unlikely to be unmarshaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is:

- Unmarshal the input XML stream into a `ProductIn` variable `in`
- Copy the desired data from `in` to a `ProductOut` variable `out`, using any necessary transformation, including `for ... range` loop over lists.

If a whole sub-tree of `ProductOut` matches exactly the structure of a sub-tree of `ProductIn`, then you can assign (e.g. `out.PriceBands = in.ProductHeader.PriceBands`) without an explicit loop. Warning: the `in` and `out` objects now share some memory by reference (via slices), and modifying `in` might modify `out`. That's fine if `in` is not used anymore.

In any case I don't recommend at all using reflection for repeated fields, they should convert into slices just fine.

Comment: Thanks for that I have come to a similar conclusion after much hacking around. I have also ascertained that what had confused me was that in the struct sub-tree assignment, not only do the members of the two structs have to have the same names and types *so do their annotations*. I.e. ```LowerQty  float32 `xml:"LowerQty"` => LowerQty  float32 `json:"lowerQty"` ```fails.

My working version here: https://play.golang.org/p/F12LlVFisZ-

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type ProductHeaders struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name   `xml:"ProductHeader"`
    Products []Products `xml:"Products"`
}

type Products struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"Products"`
    Id      string   `xml:"Id"`
    Product Product  `xml:"Product"`
}
type Product struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name   `xml:"Product"`
    PriceBands PriceBands `xml:"PriceBands"`
}
type PriceBand struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"PriceBand" json:"-"`
    UnitPrice string   `xml:"UnitPrice" json:"unitPrice"`
    LowerQty  string   `xml:"LowerQty" json:"lowerQty"`
    UpperQty  string   `xml:"UpperQty" json:"upperQty"`
}
type PriceBands struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name    `xml:"PriceBands"`
    PriceBand []PriceBand `xml:"PriceBand"`
}

func main() {

    xmlFile, err := os.Open("/home/prakash/Desktop/demo.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    var hdrs ProductHeaders

    out := make(map[string]interface{}) // USING MAP OF INTERFACE
    err = xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &hdrs)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for _, val := range hdrs.Products {
        out["productId"] = val.Id
        data, err := json.Marshal(val.Product.PriceBands.PriceBand)
        // MODIFY THE LOGIC HERE AS PER NEED
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        out["priceBands"] = string(data)
    }
    fmt.Println(out)
    //map[priceBands:[{"unitPrice":"25.75","lowerQty":"0.00","upperQty":"100.00"},{"unitPrice":"23.99","lowerQty":"100.01","upperQty":"1000.00"},{"unitPrice":"21.00","lowerQty":"1000.01","upperQty":"NULL"}] productId:123XYZ]

}
```

Here is the output:

> `map[priceBands:[{"unitPrice":"25.75","lowerQty":"0.00","upperQty":"100.00"},{"unitPrice":"23.99","lowerQty":"100.01","upperQty":"1000.00"},{"unitPrice":"21.00","lowerQty":"1000.01","upperQty":"NULL"}] productId:123XYZ]`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It may prove useful but having done more hacking around, I believe I will be able to use thee answer from Deleplace below. I have a lot of this XML to process so I may need this in the future.